# QtCharts Axis Alignment Center

Tags: c++, qt, alignment, qt5, qtcharts

I'm trying to use QtCharts with X-Axis and Y-Axis in the center of chart.

Therefore the center point will locate in the middle of my QtChart... There are options to alignment axis to the top/bottom or left/right (`addAxis(QValueAxis*,Qt::AlignTop)`). But, there is no option to align it to the center. When I use `AlignCenter` as `addAxis` argument, I get an error.

Any Help?

Tanks.

Edit (Providing code and error):

```
QChart *BScopeChart = new QChart();
QLineSeries *BScopeSerie = new QLineSeries(this);
BScopeChart->setMargins(QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0));

QValueAxis *BScopeAxisX = new QValueAxis;
BScopeAxisX->setRange(-50, 50);
QValueAxis *BScopeAxisY = new QValueAxis;
BScopeAxisY->setRange(-5, 5);

BScopeChart->addAxis(BScopeAxisY, Qt::AlignLeft); // I need this Line change to something like: BScopeChart->addAxis(BScopeAxisY, Qt::AlignCenter)
BScopeChart->addAxis(BScopeAxisX, Qt::AlignBottom); // I need this Line change to something like: BScopeChart->addAxis(BScopeAxisX, Qt::AlignCenter);

ui.widgetBScopeQChart->setChart(BScopeChart);
```

and when I change those two lines to:

```
BScopeChart->addAxis(BScopeAxisY, Qt::AlignCenter);
BScopeChart->addAxis(BScopeAxisX, Qt::AlignCenter);
```

I face this error:
[ErrorScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qblr.jpg)

Comment: Please, provide your code and the exact error.

Comment: Could you make a quick check and change Qt::AlignCenter to Qt::AlignVCenter and Qt::AlignHCenter? Also, please take a look if you're using ui as a pointer.

Comment: @JoshThuner Tanks for reply. I used Qt::AlignVCenter and Qt::AlignHCenter but same error again. I've some search in Qt assistant and I realized it's just possible to use Qt::AlignRight/Left/Bottom/Top as argument so it seems that using this function for this purpose is basically wrong. Any alternative solution?

Comment: My bad. I'm afraid that it won't be possible by using basic QChart functionalities. If we take a look at the code, we can see that only horizontal and vertical are accepted: 
https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/axis/qabstractaxis.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts20QAbstractAxisPrivate12setAlignmentE6QFlagsIN2Qt13AlignmentFlagEE

Comment: @JoshThunar So it means that I have use other widgets like qcustomplot or something like that?

Comment: @AliAbtahi Yes, if you're familiar with such tools I think Qwt allows those operations with https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_plot_scale_item.html